# Subscript inside brackets in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, brackets, subscript

I want to add brackets [] around an expression in ggplot. In my code I want the brackets around the "O2" expression.
I have tried this code for naming the y axis of my plot. But it does not work, where am I going wrong here?

```
scale_y_continuous(name = bquote('[O'[2], ']'[crit]~(mg~O[2]/L^-'1'))
```

I get the error "Error in as.environment(where) : invalid object for 'as.environment'"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bquote` can be fixed i.e.

```
 ... +
    scale_y_continuous(name = bquote("["*O[2]*"]"[crit]~(mg~O[2]/L^-1)))
```

-testing

```
plot(1, 1, main = bquote("["*O[2]*"]"[crit]~(mg~O[2]/L^-1)))
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why are you using `bquote` here since you don't seem to be inserting any values, a regular `expression` or `quote` should be just fine. Also if you check the `?plotmath` help page, you'll see the `group()` and `bgroup()` functions where are usefult for surrounding elements in delimiters. You can use

```
scale_y_continuous(name = expression(group("[", O[2], "]")[crit]~(mg~O[2]/L^-'1')))
```

This will also with with `bquote` too if you really want to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with "expression" and "paste" but I'm still interested to know how I can do this with "bquote"

```
scale_y_continuous(name = expression(paste("[O"[2], "]"[crit]~(mg~O[2]/L^-'1')))
```